# angular.element to trigger click event doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

I've been trying to trigger a click event in my input element using a angular ng-click in other element, like this:

**html**

```
<div class="myClass" ng-click="vm.selectImage()" nv-file-drop uploader="vm.uploadImage">
    Drop your image here
</div>
<div ng-hide="!hideInput">
    <input type="file" id="imgSelect" nv-file-selec uploader="vm.uploadImage" />
</div>
```

**controller**

```
vm.selectImage= selectImage;
function selectImage() {
    angular.element('#imgSelect').trigger('click');
};
```

I know there is other similar questions to this, but I've tried to use what they said (which a bunch of them shows the same code I'm using), for example:

- [how can i trigger the click event of another element in ng-click using angularjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24628410/how-can-i-trigger-the-click-event-of-another-element-in-ng-click-using-angularjs)
- [angular-file-upload - how to make drop zone clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31608032/angular-file-upload-how-to-make-drop-zone-clickable/31972856#31972856)
- [How to get element by classname or id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23609171/how-to-get-element-by-classname-or-id)

But even with that, or even using a directive like this:

```
.directive('selectImg', selectImg);
function selectImg() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.bind('click', function(e) {
                //option 1
                angular.element(e.target).siblings('.imgSelect').trigger('click');

                //option 2
                angular.element( document.querySelector( '#imgSelect' ) ).trigger('click');

                //option 3
                var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#imgSelect' ) );
                myEl.trigger('click');

                //option 4
                angular.element('#imgSelect').trigger('click'); //angular way
            });
        }
    };
};
```

I keep getting this error:

> Error: [jqLite:nosel] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-beta.1/jqLite/nosel

Here is a plunker to demonstrate the error: http://plnkr.co/edit/rWcCbixwFArYhCxUVTsv?p=preview

What is the problem?

Comment: Please create a plunkr that demonstrates the problem

Comment: @GaneshKumar I've updated my question with a plunker.

Comment: The problem is that you are not doing it Angular way, so not surprisingly it doesn't work. All your versions are not reliable, because they try to deal with DOM that is not in directive context, so the template is likely not be in DOM when you try to use it.

Comment: angular.element() does not have trigger() method. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: remove the selectors or add jquery,jqury lite doesnt support selectors

Comment: Then why the other answers tell to do it, and are acceptable? Or, how should I do it with only AngularJs? I have no plans to insert jQuery in my project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ok updated my answer this works.It appears that you have to break out of the current $apply() cycle. One way to do this is using $timeout()

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('imgSelect').click()        
 }, 0);
```

check answer [Trigger input file click event in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28762293/trigger-input-file-click-event-in-angularjs)

Comment: There is no more errors in the console. But shouldn't it open the input to add a file?